# How was this value of ObjectGUID encoded?

Tags: encoding, active-directory

An application stores the `objectGUID` of a user's MSAD entry internally as:

```
msad://OBJECTGUID=\5c\78\33\6d\77\d8\df\44\80\07\d2\77\da\d5\c5\69?USER
```

Below are the Uids I see when I pull the user's details using `ldapsearch` command:

```
...
objectGUID:: XHgzbXfY30SAB9J32tXFaQ==
ibm-entryUuid: {base64binary}XHgzbXfY30SAB9J32tXFaQ==
objectSid:: AQUAAAAAAAUVAAAAJnYeL8CFOF0H5TsrNU0lAA==
employeeNumber: 502075089
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how the application is encoding the MSAD's `objectGUID` into `msad://OBJECTGUID=\5c\78\33\6d\77\d8\df\44\80\07\d2\77\da\d5\c5\69?USER`?

I basically have to decode the applications encoding of `objectGUID`.. to identify the corresponding MSAD entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is exactly the same data displayed in hexadecimal instead of Base64.

---

In the LDIF format, which `ldapsearch` outputs, two colons means the following value is base64-encoded (usually because it has binary data). For example, these are equivalent:

```
greeting: Hello

greeting:: SGVsbG8=
```

So if you run `XHgzbXfY30SAB9J32tXFaQ==` (the value of `objectGUID`) through a base64 decoder, you will get:

```
$ echo XHgzbXfY30SAB9J32tXFaQ== | base64 -d | xxd
0000000: 5c78 336d 77d8 df44 8007 d277 dad5 c569  \x3mw..D...w...i
```

In your `msad://` URI, the same GUID is stored in hexadecimal, each byte prefixed with a `\`.